# Specific font showing Thai characters in Word fonts dropdown list

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, fonts, office365, microsoft-word-2016

In Microsoft Word, some fonts show a few characters of non-latin text next to the font name, in the dropdown list (see image below). What is that? Why is it here at all?

[image]

**สวัสดี** apparently means "hello" in Thai language... My OS is not in Thai language, nor do I have any Thai language support installed.

The same happens in other Office apps.

The font was deployed via GPO by copying the font from a shared network drive and manually adding the registry key. The behavior is identical on multiple Windows 10 computers on which it was deployed.

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing with the Gotham font, after manually adding the registry keys, and after trying the built-in "install for all users" function. Did you ever find out why this was happening?

Comment: @EmilioGarcia nope, I didn't. Months later, it's still showing the same weird characters...

Answer (score -1):

This means the font is use for Thai language.

Comment: Would you be kind enough to provide additional information? What does it mean *is use for Thai language*? What is the source of this information?